# How to retrieve Unknown XML from soap web service and insert into database using java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I want to retrieve XML response (SOAP web service) using JAVA.
The client will send the request in an XML format and java code should be able to receive a response in XML format.

Example of one XML is as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="WebService">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:SystemStatus soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <order xsi:type="xsd:int">?</order>
      </web:SystemStatus>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Could you suggest steps to implement using java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the request, you can use `java.net.HttpURLConnection`

```
String soapXml =   "";// your request_xml_in_question
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("your_Service_url");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


// Set the necessary header fields
conn.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "your_Service_url");
conn.setDoOutput(true);


// Send the request
java.io.OutputStreamWriter wr = new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(soapXml);
wr.flush();


// Read the response
java.io.BufferedReader rd = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: The request is not known to me, Is there any other way to parse the XML request?

Comment: I do not understand request not known? Have a method and let caller call the request, or read it from some file or anywhere.

Comment: Basically I want soap webservice using HTTP request and HTTP response(HTTP Servlet).
I wanted to test it using SOAPUI tool. If client sends XML as a request, I will need to read the request and the same needs to dump in the database.

Comment: you don't want to use java? you want to use client request in soapui tool from some file?

Comment: I want to use java servlet to read the requested XML and dump the requested XML into my database. It is possible that we can chat, if yes please tell me the time, I will become online.